# OpenGL 3.3 vertex buffer deletion before frame finished

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer

This is an advanced OpenGL question and tbh. it seems more like a driver bug. I know that the standard explicitly states, that deletion of an object only deletes it's name, therefore a generator function can return the same name. However it's not clear on how to deal with this...

The situation is the following: I have a so called "transient" (C++) object (TO from now on), which generates GL objects, enqueues commands using them, then deletes them.

Now consider that I use more than one of this kind before I call SwapBuffers(). The following happens:

- TO 1. generates a vertex buffer named VBO1, along with a VAO1 and other things
- TO 1. calls some mapping/drawing commands with VBO1
- TO 1. deletes the VAO1 and VBO1 (therefore the name VBO1 is freed)
- TO 2. generates a vertex buffer object, now of course with the same name (VBO1) as the name 1 is deleted and available, along with another VAO (probably 1)
- TO 2. calls some other mapping/drawing commands with this new VBO1 (different vertex positions, etc.)
- TO 2. deletes the new VBO1
- SwapBuffers()

And the result is: only the modifications performed by TO 1. are in effect. In a nutshell: I wanted to render a triangle, then a square, but I only got the triangle.

Workaround: not deleting the VBO, so I get a new name in TO 2. (VBO2)

I would like to ask for your help in this matter; although I'm aware of the fact that I *shouldn't* delete/generate objects mid-frame, but aside that, this "buggy" mechanism **really disturbs me** (I mean how can I trust GL then?...short answer: I can't...)

*(sideonote: I've been programming 3D graphics since 12 years, but this thing really gave me the creeps...)*

Comment: Could you add the relevant code so we can reproduce this?

Comment: unfortunately, no since it's being a job related code... the only thing I could try is to reproduce it with some of my existing codes, but that takes time... I will see what I can do. In the meantime tho, please DON'T wait for me...

Comment: Are you sure you unmap before deleting anything? Does calling `glFlush()` before swapbuffers help? Without seeing code, these are shots in the dark.

Comment: "*I have a so called "transient" (C++) object (TO from now on), which generates GL objects, enqueues commands using them, then deletes them.*" Here's an idea: *stop doing that*. "Transient" storage should be accomplished by creating a buffer persistently and sub-allocating sections from it. Not by constantly creating and destroying buffer objects. If you are calling `glGenBuffers` every frame, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas What if there isn't enough GPU RAM to hold all data in a frame? Or buffers for data change their size in every frame?

Comment: @Ripi2: Then he wouldn't be able to render the scene at all, and with his way, the call to `glBufferData` would fail. Either way, it fails. But this way removes the improper use of the API. "*Or buffers for data change their size in every frame?*" That's why you "*sub*-allocate" from the main buffer object.

Comment: the problem is, that one wouldn't except something from ogl... I did it with vulkan, ok... but ogl??? Being this case I could say to my managers that "well guys, ogl just sucks, we should move to vulkan"... LIKE HELL... But tbh. since they're being the same group (Khronos), I would recommend to abaondon ogl altogether... With my experience I can say that it is worse than a joke...

Comment: and trust me, I unmap everything correctly.... and I use glBufferData for allocation only. After that I only use glMapBufferRange (YES, with the correct flags...)

Comment: To me, this sounds like some bug in how you set  up the GL state (the GL deletion semantic can also be a bit unintuitive, as deleting does not only delete the name, but might as well unbind the object if still bound to containers which are also currently bound - but not from other containers still referencing them). You can do as many create-delete-cycles per frame as you want - GL doesn't really have a concept of a "frame" at all (at least from the user's perspective), and your "I shouldn't delete/generate objects mid-frame" remark is just completely baseless.

Comment: I thought the same...and of course I'm still looking for my error in the code, but I proved in my code that not deleting the VBO solves the problem. That's why I said that it might be a driver bug. But if it is, then the whole standard is unrealiable...working on a project like this, it's a huge disappointment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem, I think it's worth mentioning (so that other developers won't fall into the same hole). The actual problem is the VAO, or more precisely the *caching* of the VAO.

In Metal and Vulkan the input layout is completely independent of the actual buffers used: you only specify the binding point (location) where the buffer is going to be.

But not in OpenGL... the VAO actually holds a strong reference to the vertex buffer which was bound during it's creation. Therefore the following thing happened:

- VBO1 was created, VAO1 was created
- VAO1 was cached in the pipeline cache
- VBO1 was deleted, but only the name was freed, not the object
- glGenBuffers() returns 1 again as the name is available
- but VAO1 in the cache still references the old VBO1
- the driver gets confused and doesn't let me modify the new VBO1

And the solution...well... For now when a vertex buffer gets deleted I delete any cached pipelines that reference that buffer.

On the long term tho: I'm going to maintain a separate cache for input layouts (even if it's part of the pipeline state), and move the transient object further up, so that it becomes less transient.

Welcome to the world of OpenGL...

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems with my multithreaded rendering code.  I use a double buffering system for the render commands, so when I delete an object, it might be used in the next frame.

The short of it is that TO shouldn't directly delete the GL objects.  It needs to submit the handle to a manager to **queue** for deletion between frames.  With my double buffering, I add a small timer to count down 2 frames before releasing.

For my transient verts, I have a large chunk of memory that I write to for storage, and skip the VBO submission. I don't know what your setup is or how many vertices you are pushing, but you may not benefit from VBOs if you  1) regenerate every frame or 2) push small sets of verts.  Definitely perf test with and without VBOs.

Comment: exactly...my code is multithreaded too (thus the approach). Your suggestion seems pretty much the same as my idea (make the object less transient), so in the last resort I will implement a manager class.